# Obtaining Details of Previously Submitted Non-Immigrant Visa

Tags: visa

I would like to know if there is possibility of obtaining full details of the previously submitted and approved US visa?

I was able to retrieve the application by providing application number and security questions but it only showed the confirmation paper and not the full detail.

Comment: What detail beyond that provided by the application are you interested in?

Comment: @phoog contact information of the person in the states

Comment: Of the person whose visa it is?  There is no other part of the visa process apart from the application where such information is supplied to the State Department.

Comment: @phoog I didnt really understand your question, but, there is a filed in b2 visa where the contact details of the person of interest in US is added. My question is how can one access all such details in a submitted application. Including the medical question s that were answered etc.

Comment: Aha, I see.  They probably can't release that unless you prove that you are the applicant, because of privacy laws.  Was it your application?

Comment: @phoog yes it was mine. I tried accessing by adding the application number, security question etc. The only thing that appeared was the confirmation page with the photo. Not the details